# Правилен ли мой перевод с английского на русский?

Tags: грамотная-речь, переводы

Дело в том, что русский язык - не мой родной язык. Помогите, пожалуйста,  с этим переводом (какие ошибки я сделала? есть ли фразы в тексте, которые  следует исправить?).

*Перестань беспокоиться о своей личности и заботься о людях, которые тебе важны, об идеях, имеющих значение, об убеждениях, которые можно поддерживать и о билетах, которые можно использовать.   Разумные люди делают этот выбор своим умом и сердцем, и они делают их в одиночку. Мир не доставляет смысл жизни. Ты должен сделать его значимым ... и решить, что ты хочешь и что надо и что обязательно делать. Это трудный, невообразимо одинокий и сложный способ быть в мире. Но это дело: надо жить; невозможно жить слоганами, мертвыми идеями, клише или национальными флагами. Найти личность легко. Это простой выход.*

> Stop worrying about your identity and concern yourself with the people
>   you care about, ideas that matter to you, beliefs you can stand by,
>   tickets you can run on. Intelligent humans make those choices with
>   their brain and hearts and they make them alone. The world does not
>   deliver meaning to you. You have to make it meaningful…and decide what
>   you want and need and must do. It’s a tough, unimaginably lonely and
>   complicated way to be in the world. But that’s the deal: you have to
>   live; you can’t live by slogans, dead ideas, clichés, or national
>   flags. Finding an identity is easy. It’s the easy way out.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Well, there are no obvious semantic errors, but the style is unsuccessful.  You are appreciated making your quest here https://russian.stackexchange.com/  You are welcome to cоmmunicate in English in there.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что identity ― это не личность, а идентичность, то есть отождествление себя с людьми, идеями и т.д. Человек должен иметь свои идеи, а не искать среди готовых подходящие для себя. **Иначе смысл текст неясен, особенно концовка.**

Перестаньте беспокоиться о своей идентичности  и заботиться о людях, которые вам небезразличны, об идеях, которые важны для вас, об  убеждения, которые вы поддерживаете, о возможностях, которые вам открываются. Умные люди делают свой выбор умом и сердцем, и делают это в одиночестве.  Мир не раскроет вам своего значения. Вы должны сделать его значимым и решить, что вы хотите, в чем нуждаетесь, и должны действовать. Это трудный, невообразимо одинокий и сложный путь существования  в мире. Но вот в чем дело: вы должны жить, вы не можете жить лозунгами, мертвыми идеями, клише или национальными флагами. Поиск идентичности ― это легко. Это самый простой выход.

Answer (score 0):

Буквальный перевод близок к тексту и неплохо передаёт смысл каждого предложения. Поэтому достаточно отредактировать текст (с оглядкой на оригинал), чтобы сделать его более "русским" и понятным:

> Отвлекитесь от забот о собственной личности и сосредоточьтесь на
>   людях, которые вам небезразличны, на интересных вам идеях, на
>   убеждениях, которых вам стоит придерживаться, на шансах, которые
>   можно использовать. Люди мыслящие делают такой выбор умом и сердцем, и делают
>   его сами. Мир не раскроет вам смысла жизни. Вам придётся самому
>   придать ей смысл... и решить, чего вы хотите, что вам нужно и чем вы
>   должны заниматься. Жизнь в этом мире - трудный, невообразимо одинокий
>   и сложный путь. Но в том-то и дело: жить вам придётся, а в жизни
>   нельзя руководствоваться лозунгами, мёртвыми идеями, стереотипами или
>   государственным флагом. Найти же своё место несложно. В этом и есть
>   простой выход.

Comment: Только хуже сделали. Имхо. В английском - живая дружеская речь, у вас - проповедь какого-то сектанта.

Comment: *Мир не раскроет вам смысла жизни. Вам придётся самому придать ей смысл..* - вот это вообще никуда не годится. Там другой смысл. Не "раскроет",  а сам по себе не является смыслом, не порождает его. Ты должен этот смысл сам для себя сделать значимым, реальным. Не искать счастью, а создавать его. Как-то так....

Comment: Трудно сохранить легкость стиля, не уходя далеко от оригинала. Может, сказать просто: Смысл жизни не существует сам по себе. Ты сам должен внести смысл в свою жизнь ...и решить, чего ты хочешь, что тебе нужно и что ты должен делать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну уж коли начали свои варианты выкладывать... Я чуть-чуть отошел от прямого перевода ради смысла и духа.

*Перестань беспокоиться о себе, о своей личности и сконцентрируйся (сосредоточься?) на людях, которые нуждаются в твоей заботе, на важных для тебя идеях, на принципах, которые ты готов отстаивать, на шансах, которые тебе выпадают (предоставляются?) Разумные (мыслящие?) люди выбирают [стезю] умом и сердцем, и выбирают самостоятельно. Мир не предоставит тебе смысла жизни. Ты должен сделать мир значимым для тебя и решить, что ты сам хочешь, и что хочешь и можешь сделать для этого. Это сложный, невообразимо томящий одиночеством и сложный способ существовать в этом мире. Но в этом суть, в этом и заключается сама жизнь. Ты не должен жить по лозунгам, мертворожденным идеям, клише или под флагом национальной идеи. Найти себя легко. И это простой выход из всего.*

Не претендую на многое, это набросок, не все получилось, замечания категорически приветствуются

Comment: Care about - не о "заботе": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212975/care-about-and-care-for

Comment: "Мир не предоставит тебе смысла жизни" - фраза имеет сильный привкус английского. См. также мой комментарий к ответу Alex_ander

Comment: @Мимоходов  "Это сложный, невообразимо томящий одиночеством и сложный способ существовать в этом мире" - так задумано? Или вместо повтора возможно другое прилагательное?

Comment: Лозунги (клише, идеи) не бывают «мертворожденными», бывает недолгим срок их актуальности, после чего они могут стать не только мертвыми, но еще: устарелыми, обветшалыми, сухими, безжизненными, а также бессмысленными, размытыми, спорными и пр.
Однако, как лично мне кажется, смысл фразы со словом флаг следует передавать вовсе без определений, например так: «Ты не должен слепо (бездумно) следовать лозунгам (призывам), клише, идеям и приоритетам мирового или национального масштаба».

Comment: *Лозунги (клише, идеи) не бывают «мертворожденными»* guaranteen - не принято. "Мертворождённая идея (перен.: нежизненная, бесплодная). Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992"

Comment: *Однако, как лично мне кажется, смысл фразы со словом флаг следует передавать вовсе без определений* - возможно. Но вы-то смысл совсем переделали. В оригинале флаг - это именно неуий путеводный символ.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова - это как-то само получилось. Не задумывалось.

Comment: М_Г - *фраза имеет сильный привкус английского* - возмложно потому, что я начал думать по-английски ))). По-русски сказать совершенно не получалось без существенногй потери смысла.. Есть варианты?

Comment: @Alex_ander  *Care about - не о "заботе* - почему? В русском же есть разговорное "не твоя забота"? Я именно в таком значении имел в виду. Да я бы и рад сказать по-друголму, но как? "Люди которые важны" - это бьёт по моему чутью как скрежет очищаемой сковороды  по ушам Моцарта.

Comment: Это идиома со значением "относиться к  кому-то как к дорогому, близкому, быть к нему небезразличным" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/care+about Заботиться - to care for или to take care of

Comment: Соглашусь с тем, что идеи бывают «мертворожденными». Но это именно те идеи, что остались только на бумаге и известны узкому кругу исследователей, то есть те идеи, которым не суждено было  овладеть «массовым сознанием», стать популярными (плодотворными). Своим (угловато сформулированным) замечанием хотел обратить внимание на тот факт, что в рассматриваемом контексте речь может идти о любых идеях, за исключением «мертворожденных».

Comment: Да, фразу пришлось полностью переделать. Во первых, потому, что вызвал сомнения стиль изложения (текста перевода), а во вторых, потому, что хотелось следовать смыслу суждения (высказывания) в целом: «Откажись от глобальных ориентиров (шаблонов, штампов), ищи свой путь».